# How to disable swapfile only for specific actions?

Tags: 18.04, asus, swap, copy

When I copy a big file in ubuntu 18.04.4, ubuntu lags and the whole system gets slower.
I searched for this issue and one solution was [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive/107722#107722).
But it didn't worked for me.
Then I found the second solution [here](https://gist.github.com/2E0PGS/f63544f8abe69acc5caaa54f56efe52f), that says just disable swapfile. And it worked on my system.
Now the problem is that I do machine learning works and I think that I need the swapfile.
Is there a way that swapfile be disabled just when copying files?
Or do you have any other solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do what you'd like, however, there is a manual way. Before copying big files, open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo swapoff
```

Press the Enter key and it will ask for your password. It is the same one you use to Log In. Close the terminal and do your copying. When you are done copying large files, open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo swapon
```

Use the same instructions (above) and your swap will be re-enabled.

Source: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/swapon.htm

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. "Swap" is a system-level action, and when swapping happens, the identity of the program is not available to the swapping code.